# Postgres function error : Unterminated dollar quote

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I wrote the following postgres function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION nameFunction() 
        RETURNS VOID AS $$
        DECLARE rec RECORD;
        BEGIN
           FOR rec IN EXECUTE 'Select ....'
           LOOP
               UPDATE ...;
               SELECT ...;
               IF (condition) IS NULL THEN
                 INSERT ...;
               END IF;
               SELECT ..;
               INSERT INTO ..;
           END LOOP;
        END;
        $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I have this error:

```
Unterminated dollar quote started... DECLARE rec RECORD. Expected terminating $$
```

Somebody can help me?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Which tool do you use to run that?

Comment: Try removing the indentation before the closing `$$`, and also the semicolon `;` before it

Comment: I am using pgAdmin tool

Comment: there's nothing wrong with function , would you mind providing the full function?

Comment: Works for me (or at least gets farther than that before failing).  The part that caused the problem is someplace you haven't shown us, like in the  ellipses, or in how this command was invoked.